# Add progress bar while downloading file with Python remotezip

Tags: python

There're already questions about how to print a progress bar while downloading a file with `requests` module but I've never seen such with `remotezip`. Already had a look into remotezip's source code:

```
class RemoteZip(zipfile.ZipFile):
    def __init__(self, url, initial_buffer_size=64*1024, session=None, fetcher=RemoteFetcher, support_suffix_range=True,
                 **kwargs):
        fetcher = fetcher(url, session, support_suffix_range=support_suffix_range, **kwargs)
        rio = RemoteIO(fetcher.fetch, initial_buffer_size)
        super(RemoteZip, self).__init__(rio)
        rio.set_position_to_size(self._get_position_to_size())

    def _get_position_to_size(self):
        ilist = [info.header_offset for info in self.infolist()]
        if len(ilist) == 0:
            return {}
        ilist.sort()
        ilist.append(self.start_dir)
        return {a: b-a for a, b in pairwise(ilist)}
```

It looks like `remotezip` treats a URL like a ZIP file then the rest of the work is for `zipfile` (a context open a URL as `RemoteZip` and then read with `ZipFile.read()` a file inside the archive). Therefore, I have no clue how the reading progress is going. So I wonder how to add the progress bar indicating the true progress of downloading a file with `remotezip`? Thank you

Comment: Why would progress bars be related to either `requests` or `removezip` at all? A good progress bar library is independent of "the thing that's doing the task you're showing the progress for". It just needs to update correctly based on your code telling it what the current progress is. There are a whole bunch of pages on the web that talk about how to add a progress bar to whatever your code is, including names of libraries that they use to achieve that.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans How can it be independent? It needs to know the state of the task whose progress you're showing. And the task has to provide updated state periodically, typically through a callback. There's no generic way to do this.

Comment: It just needs you to send it a signal telling it what the current progress is, and it does the rest. For `requests`, that means you have an event loop based on transfer size, for remotezip, I don't know what the event loop would be, so _that_ is the part you're interested in, not the "progress bar" part. That part is trivial once you know what function or event notification `remotezip` offers for getting some kind of progress _value_ out.

Comment: actually I've been looking for the event loop, the part where remotezip is able to send the signal of the current state (in fact it doesn't) and add it by doing some monkey-patching (to modify remotezip code without modifying the source code's content)

Comment: See [ask]. It's too broad. Research more, try to implement a prototype and ask a specific question. At least you should understand the implementation of the internal classes ```RemoteIO``` and ```RemoteFetcher```.

Comment: It's too broad because there are many possible ways and it takes too much efforts to implement one example solution. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: I'm not asking for an example solution. I need help to find where the event loop is